# Subquery to fetch a property NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql, viewmodel, criteria

I'm using NHibernate for a web application. I have a model like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel {
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   /* others simple properties */

   public virtual IList<OfferViewModel> LastOffers { get; set; }

   public ProductViewModel() { }
}
public class OfferViewModel {
   public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
   public virtual decimal Prince { get; set; }

   public OfferViewModel() { }
}
```

I would like to know, how to fetch the "LastOffers" collection property with a HQL subquery ? I want to fetch it with top 10 last offers. I have my model mapped correctly but I don't know the sintax to do a subquery fetch this property.

Today, I'm using a command like this to fetch my ViewModel:

```
public IList<ProductViewModel> GetProductsForSalles()
        {
            return
                Session.CreateQuery(@"select p.Id as Id, 
                                             p.Name as Name,
                                             p.Price as Price,
                                             p.Price as Date
                                             /* FETCH LastOffers? */
                                       from Product p  
                                       where p.Active=true and (p.Status=:Status)
                                       order by a.Date asc")
                    .SetParameter("Status", Status.Started)
                    .SetMaxResults(50)
                    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProductViewModel>())
                    .List<ProductViewModel>();
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on description you provided I guess you need to load a set of products with preloaded lastoffers, joined to products by FK. The code below should do this:

```
return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ProductViewModel), "p")
  .CreateCriteria("p.LastOffers", "lastoffers")
  .SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("p.Active", true))
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("p.Status", Status.Started))
  .SetMaxResults(50)
  .List<ProductViewModel>();
```

Not testes, but idea is that we join two tables and the result will be 'collapsed' to each row of product (by `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer`)

Sorry that the example is not in HQL - I prefer Criterias and QueryOver<> as more stable.

Comment: Hello Genius, Thanks for the awser. In fact, DistinctRootEntityResult shoul resolve my problema :), but is there any way to fetch the property with top 10 records and order by id desc ? I want this to improve performace, because I'll have a lot of offers per product. Thanks again!

Comment: @Felipe, I never used this feature, but AFAIK it supported by NH. Try to play with fetchmode parameter in a HBM file of your entity.